# What was this early 2000s software subscription that had a billboard theme and was about music and bands?

Tags: software, identify-this-software, music

I cannot remember the name of this music software CDs I used to have. We would get it in the mail every month and it had interviews and song samples in a game style UI with a city/billboard theme. Sorta like MTV but not MTV

Comment: Any particular country?

Comment: What is "misic"?

Comment: Was it perhaps [Blender](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blender_(magazine))?